# CSS adds automatic margin on small screens in portrait mode

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: auto;
      width: 720px;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

When running this on a Full HD screen in portrait mode, everything is fine: The paragraph width is 720px. If I change the width to 1080px it is fine aswell: There is no margin - the paragraph goes from one side of the page to the other.

But if I I try to view this on a 720x1280 HD screen in portrait mode, a 130px margin is added automatically.

Why does this happen? Is margin: auto messing up on smaller screens? How do I fix it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You would be better of applying your `margin: auto` to your paragraphs, as the `body` is the wrapper of your entire content, and even changing the background color will become a hassle like this. At most set the margin of the body to `0`, but dont use that element (or the HTML element) to center things inside it.

Comment: you given width 720px; so, it shows html without margin untill 720px; but if you go screen bigger than this you will see content in center, so, automatically gives margin both sides(actually it is not margin but it makes content in center)

Comment: @ashup. My point is: It adds a margin on a 720px screen, even though it should fill the screen

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style>
    body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:720px;}
 </style>
```

This should work, check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xwL6z4c7/).